# Timeout command breaks command that expects input

Tags: bash, timeout

I need to execute a command with timeout so it's killed after X time.

I have done tests and it only works when typed in the terminal directly, when in a bash script it seems to not handle the user input like it's not "receiving it"

Comment: What is the script? what input does the script accept?

Comment: @val0x00ff I solved it, should I delete this question?

Comment: You can post your own answer and accept is as solved. It could help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution looking at the man page. You need to use `timeout --foreground 120s` to have your command accept user input when executed in a bash script.

Comment: Which man page helped you ?